# Is there a way to make a button inside a Datatable clickable to send data using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am sending a request to an API and i am getting all the data and mapping it to a table and at the same time displaying a button for each row and am appending to the button an ID which is coming from the data. The problem is when i give the button an ID lets say **remove** and create a function to fire upon the button click nothing is happening not even registering that its been clicked and below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#documentsDatatable").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'https://localhost:44389/api/Document/Group',
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {id: 90},
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "name", "name": "Document", "autoWidth": true },
            {
                data: "created_at",
                "render": function (value) {
                    if (value === null) return "";
                    return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                }
            },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return "<button value='" + full.id + "' id='remove' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-minus-circle'></i> Remove from Group</button>";
                }
            },

        ]
    });
});
```

Here is the function which should fire up:

```
    $('#remove').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://localhost:44389/api/Group/Remove",
        data: {id: 4, group: 46},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log('success', data);

        },
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The above code is failing to even fire up the function but when i create a random button like below and replace the ID with the one on this button the code is working perfectly. Anyone know what the problem is?

```
<button id="trial" value="50">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return `<button onclick=remove( ${full.id}) class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-minus-circle'></i> Remove from Group</button>`;
        }
---------------------------------------------------------

        function remove (id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "https://localhost:44389/api/Group/Remove",
                data: { id: id, group: 46 },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log('success', data);

                },
            })
        };
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This worked. In my head i did not think of sending the ID to the function also. Thank you so much